# Reconstructing noisy signals treated by FFT in R

Tags: r, fft

Hello I would like to isolate all the sines and cosines that are produced by a fast Fourier transform (FFT) in R for of noisy signals. This is to illustrate the behaviour of FFT with noisy signals on small and regularly sampled time-series. I've derived a script from a Matlab explanation; https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html

The script behaves well with a simple addition of sines:

```
# Create a signal with given parameters ----

L <- 1500  # Length of data

Fs <- 1000 # Sampling frequency

Ts <- 1/Fs # Sampling rate

t <- (0:(L-1))*Ts # Time value

S1 <- 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t)
S2 <- sin(2*pi*120*t)

S <- S1 + S2

X <- S

# Uncomment to add noise ----
# set.seed(42)
# X <- S + 0.5*rnorm(length(t))

# Perform FFT on X ----

Y <- fft(X)

r1 <- Re(Y)/L
i1 <- Im(Y)/L

# Rearrange fft output to get the frequency, 
# the real and the imaginary components well identified ----

r1 <- r1[1:((L/2)+1)]
r1[2:(length(r1)-1)] <- 2 * r1[2:(length(r1)-1)]

i1 <- i1[1:((L/2)+1)]
i1[2:(length(i1)-1)] <- 2 * i1[2:(length(i1)-1)]

f <- Fs*(0:(L/2))/L

time <- t
freq <- f
real <- r1
imag <- i1

# Reconstitute each and every sine and cosine ----

lt <- length(time)
lf <- length(freq)

mtime <- matrix(rep(time, lf), nrow = lt)
mfreq <- matrix(rep(freq, lt), nrow = lt, byrow = T)

mcos <- cos(2 * pi * mtime * mfreq)
msin <- sin(2 * pi * mtime * mfreq)

acos <- matrix(rep(real, each = lt), nrow = lt)
asin <- matrix(rep(imag, each = lt), nrow = lt)

rcos <- mcos * - acos # Negative for whatever reason
rsin <- msin * - asin # Negative for whatever reason

# Add real and imaginary parts (cosines and sines) ----

comb <- rcos + rsin 

# Reconstitute the entire signal ----

synth <- rowSums(comb)

# Plot ----

par(mfrow = c(1,4))

ylim <- c(0,0.2)
xlim <- NULL

plot(X, time, type = "l", pch = 19, xlab = "Signal", 
     xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)

# 181 index of f = 120
plot(comb[,181] ,time, type = "l", xlab = "Isolated frequencies", 
     xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, lty = 5)

# 76 index of f = 50
lines(comb[,76] ,time, type = "l", lwd = 2)

plot(synth ,time, type = "l", xlab = "Reconstituted signal", 
     xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)

difference <- synth - X

hist(difference, breaks = 100, col = "black")
```

This code gives the figure that follows. The plot on the left is the signal on which I apply the FFT, the one in the middle-left is the two sines making up the signal, extracted by the FFT, and the plot on the middle right is the addition of all the sinusoids. The difference between signal and noise is characterised via the histogram on the right. It's very small, so I assume this is the results of floating point arithmetic errors, and negligible.

[image]

My problem is when I work on higly noisy signal; the FFT reconstruction becomes clearly different from the initial signal, as can be seen in the following figure (same explanation than earlier, same code, I've only uncommented the bit of code that adds noise).

[image]

The reconstructed signal is clearly different from the initial signal (despite having apparently the same variance, and the same sines that were added). Can that problem be avoided ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works using the direct Fourier transform (Glacial Fourier transform ?)

```
# Create a signal with given parameters ----

L <- 1500  # Length of data

Fs <- 1000 # Sampling frequency

Ts <- 1/Fs # Sampling rate

dt <- (0:(L-1))*Ts # Time value

S1 <- 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*dt)
S2 <- sin(2*pi*120*dt)

S <- S1 + S2

xy <- S

# Uncomment to add noise ----
set.seed(42)
xy <- S + 0.5*rnorm(length(t)) + 20

# Glacial/Direct FOurier Transform

fseq <- Fs*(0:(L/2))/L

ahr <- NULL
ahi <- NULL

for(f in fseq){

  hr <- 2*sum(xy * cos(2 * pi * f * dt))/L
  hi <- 2*sum(xy * sin(2 * pi * f * dt))/L

  ahr <- c(ahr, hr)
  ahi <- c(ahi, hi)

}

ahr[1] <- ahr[1]/2
ahi[1] <- ahi[1]/2

ahr[length(ahr)] <- ahr[length(ahr)]/2
ahi[length(ahi)] <- ahi[length(ahi)]/2

time <- dt
freq <- fseq
real <- ahr
imag <- ahi

# Reconstitute each and every sine and cosine ----

lt <- length(time)
lf <- length(freq)

mtime <- matrix(rep(time, lf), nrow = lt)
mfreq <- matrix(rep(freq, lt), nrow = lt, byrow = T)

mcos <- cos(2 * pi * mtime * mfreq)
msin <- sin(2 * pi * mtime * mfreq)

acos <- matrix(rep(real, each = lt), nrow = lt)
asin <- matrix(rep(imag, each = lt), nrow = lt)

rcos <- mcos * acos
rsin <- msin * asin

# Add real and imaginary parts (cosines and sines) ----

comb <- rcos + rsin

# Reconstitute the entire signal ----

synth <- rowSums(comb)

# Plot ----

par(mfrow = c(1,4))

ylim <- c(0,0.2)

plot(xy, time, type = "l", pch = 19, xlab = "Signal",
     ylim = ylim)

# 181 index of f = 120
plot(comb[,181] ,time, type = "l", xlab = "Isolated frequencies",
     ylim = ylim, lty = 5)

# 76 index of f = 50
lines(comb[,76] ,time, type = "l", lwd = 2)

plot(synth ,time, type = "l", xlab = "Reconstituted signal",
     ylim = ylim)

difference <- synth - xy

hist(difference, breaks = 100, col = "black")
```

[image]